# Advice. on posting a bilingual paper on arXiv

Tags: arxiv

I couldn't get this question past the spam filter to arXiv...

I am preparing to post an article that has been written in two languages (French and English).  I wanted some advice on how to make this article visible in the best way possible.

The article is an introduction article.  We are submitting in French with an English language supplemental information.  French language introductions are used world wide in Québec, France, parts of Africa, and more where paid journal articles are not always easily available.  I expect this article will be useful for French speaking students to have both the English and French versions, so the French language article will have an English language translation as a supplement.  I also think our presentation will be useful to both audiences.

I wanted it was better to submit an arXiv version as two separate submissions for the English language supplemental and the French language main article.  Another option would be to make the second version the English language version.  Still another option is to bundle the English and French versions together in one (very long) pdf.  Does anyone have advice to make sure this is visible, searchable, and both versions are linked to each other?

Comment: Vaguely related - some European based journals used to have the abstract in English, French, and German, with the main article in one of those. Haven't looked at one in a while to see if those particular ones still did that.

Comment: Generally speaking, there is a consensus that scientifically relevant articles are communicated in English. If your paper is "for students", then it *may* not be a novel scientific contribution, and if that is the case, then probably arXiv is simply not the place for this paper. You can always use Zenodo or any other repository that is less about novel research and more about information sharing. If this is not your case feel free to ignore this comment.

Comment: It's not too uncommon in this field to produce introductions to the field.  it's relatively new, and from the feedback we've gotten, there's a significant improvement in the presentation and the students have felt they had a better grasp of what is going on.  I think it belongs on arXiv for certain, but thank you for the alternative view.